# Command to get update version details of an ESXi machine

Tags: command, esxi

I have run "vmware -v" and "vmware -l" commands on an ESXi 5.0 U1 and got the outputs as "VMware ESXi 5.0.0 build-504890" and "VMware ESXi 5.0.0 GA". But, nowhere I get the information of the update for this version. eg. it is ESXi 5.0 Update 1, I am not finding any command to get the update version. Tried googling around the whole day, but of no help. Any help will be highly appreciated.

Answer (score 0):

For ESXi 4, run this command:

**vmkvsitools vmware -l**

For ESXi 5, run this command:

**esxcli system version get**

These commands will provide the exact Update for the version of ESXi running.